# Updating an auto_now DateTimeField in a parent model in Django Framework

Tags: python, django, database, orm

I've got two models: Message and Attachment. Each attachment is attached to a specific message, using a ForeignKey on the Attachment model. Both models have an auto_now DateTimeField called updated. I'm trying to make it so that when any attachment is saved, it also sets the updated field on the associated message to now. Here's my code:
`def save(self): super(Attachment, self).save() self.message.updated = self.updated`

Will this work, and if you can explain it to me, why? If not, how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct! Calling self.message.save() ensures that the changes to the associated message's updated field are persisted to the database. This way, both the attachment and the associated message will have their updated fields updated when an attachment is saved.

Answer (score 0):

`auto_now=True` will *ignore* anything you set to it, and will use the current timestamp.

Indeed, take a look at the [`.pre_save(…)` of a `DateTimeField` <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/427f0ed98d7ecf4381cebd4f7773f761e2446851/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1630-L1636):

> ```
> def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
>     if self.auto_now or (self.auto_now_add and add):
>         value = timezone.now()
>         setattr(model_instance, self.attname, value)
>         return value
>     else:
>         return super().pre_save(model_instance, add)
> ```

So if `self.auto_now` or `self.auto_now_add` is used, it will omit the value, and set `timezone.now()` as value instead, regardless what you "throw" at the instance.

You thus can update the `updated` of the message, you can use:

```
def save(self):
    super().save()
    self.message.save()
```

this will however *not* guarantee that both `.updated` fields will be the same. This is because between the two queries, time will pass, and thus the timestamp can be different.